# how to include the header access token to the Dropzone config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, access-token, dropzone.js

i have to add the header access token

```
  $scope.dropzoneConfig = {
            'options': { // passed into the Dropzone constructor
                'url': 'SOME API URL' + $scope.SOME_ID
            },
            'eventHandlers': {
                'sending': function (file, xhr, formData) {
                },
                'success': function (file, response) {
                }
            }};
```

And my header access token is

```
{ headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $scope.access_token } }
```

and i need to add this to the url or the api that i am trying to call

Comment: can you tried  headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $scope.access_token
    }

Answer (score 7):

You can add the header in the `headers options` of your `dropzone` object.
Check the `headers` attribute in the options in the following example:

```
    $("#dropzone").dropzone({
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        url: "/content", 
        maxFiles: 1, 
        clickable: true, 
        acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.jpeg", 
        addRemoveLinks: true, 
        maxFilesize: 10, //MB
        headers:{"Authorization":'Bearer ' + $scope.access_token},          
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getUploadParams = ({ file, meta }) => {
    const body = new FormData();
    let headers;
    UserTool.getToken((token) => {
      headers= { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }     
      body.append('file', file, file.name)      
    });
    return { url: UrlConfig.tileset.uploadUrl, body, headers  }
  }
```